# Getting the product of 2 columns producing strange and incorrect answers

Tags: pandas

I have this simple df:

```
df
   weight  price  size
0       1     10     1
1       2      9     2
2       3      8     3
3       4      7     4
4       5      6     5
5       6      5     6
6       7      4     7
7       8      3     8
8       9      2     9
9      10      1    10
```

Now I set:

```
values = df.price * df.size
```

I get this:

```
values
0    300
1    270
2    240
3    210
4    180
5    150
6    120
7     90
8     60
9     30
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

When I went to school 1 * 10 was 10! I can't understand where the 300 is coming from!

Any tips please?

I want to set:

```
df['values'] = values
```

when the arithmetic is correct.

I can get the result with this, but using values seems much neater.

```
df['values'] = 0
for i in df.index:
    price = df.iloc[i, 1]
    size = df.iloc[i, 2]
    print(price * size)
    df[i,3] = price * size
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket notation for select column `size`:

```
values = df.price * df['size']
print (values)
0    10
1    18
2    24
3    28
4    30
5    30
6    28
7    24
8    18
9    10
dtype: int64
```

because [`DataFrame.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) get number of values in DataFrame.

Check difference:

```
print (df.size)
30

print (df['size'])
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     6
6     7
7     8
8     9
9    10
Name: size, dtype: int64
```